# Every finite generated module with finite free resolution is UFD

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

The following is exercise 2.2.27 in Bruns and Herzog's book Cohen-Macaulay rings:

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring such that every finite generated module has a finite free resolution. Then $R$ is UFD.

I don't know how to show that $R$ is integral domain. If this is true, using the proof of "regular local ring is UFD" in this book. Then the result follows.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Books will usually prove that regular local rings are domains.

Comment: @Mohan But this is not a local ring.

Comment: @Sky One can prove that any FFR module has zero annihilator or this contains a non-zero-divisor. In particular, if $I$ is a FFR ideal, then $I=(0)$ or $I$ contains a non-zero-divisor. Now should be easy to show that $R$ is an integral domain.

Comment: @user26857 Thanks a lot.